# Binary search with bug or inaccuracy

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search, floating-accuracy

First of all, sorry for my English.

I am solving this problem:

> Tom wants to shoot from a cannon at the Jerry, but he would like to have as many pieces as possible, but they must be the same size and as big as possible too. He only have **n** cannonballs at his disposal, so he can cut them in smaller pieces. And he would like to have **k + 1** pieces to shoot from cannon at the Jerry. He knows the radius of every cannonball. What is the biggest volume of one piece? Output is rounded printf("%.3f\n",answer). First number is **n** and the second **k** , next **n** numbers are radiuses of cannonballs.
>   Possible input:
>   3 50
>   1 2 3
>   Output: 2.900*

Here is my solution: The volume of every piece can be only smaller or equal to volume of the smallest cannonball because you cannot join parts from cannonballs together. So I have used Binary search from **0.0 to minimal volume** and as the predicate I have used function numberOfPieces, which counts the number of pieces from every cannonball with specific **volume of one piece(this is the median in binary search)**. This function return number of pieces I can get if I use **median** as volume of one piece. Then I just compare it to **k + 1** and if it is bigger or equal I use median as low otherwise I use it as high. **My solution works for this test input.**

The problem is that I get WA(wrong answer) and I cannot check the test input values. Can you please look at my code and check if I did something wrong please? The problem may be number inaccuracy, but I have small EPS so it should be good. Thanks in advance for every idea.

Here is my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI 3.14159265358979323846
#define VC ((4.0/3.0) * PI) // constant for volume calculation
#define EPS 1E-12

using namespace std;

// return the number of pieces depending on the volume
int numberOfPieces(int v[], int n, double volume)
{
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        ans += (int)(v[i] * VC / volume);
    return ans;
}


double binarySearch(double a, double b, int k, int n, int v[])
{
   double low = a, high = b;
   while(abs(low-high) > EPS)
   {
      double mid = low + (high - low) / 2.0;
      if(numberOfPieces(v, n, mid) >= k)
          low = mid;
      else
          high = mid;
   }
   return (low + high)/2.0;
}

int main()
{
    int n, k, x; // n - number of cannonballs, k - number of wanted pieces, x - variable for input
    int v[10001]; // radiuses ^ 3 of the cannonballs
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &k);
    int minVolume = 9999999;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&x);
        minVolume = min(minVolume, x);
        v[i] = x * x * x;
    }
    printf("%.3f\n", binarySearch(0.0, minVolume * minVolume * minVolume * VC, k + 1, n, v));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your code for the input that is giving a wrong answer?

Comment: at least an obvious one is should pass `minVolume * minVolume * minVolume * VC` when you call `binarySearch`, other seems ok to me

Comment: No, I cannot give you link to the problem, because it is something like a homework at my university and members only can access it. Yes, that  would be the problem at the first place, thanks a lot, but when I tried it I got TLE(Time Limit Exceeded) and when I tried smaller EPS = 1E-5 I got WA(wrong answer). I fixed minVolume * minVolume * minVolume in the code.

Comment: So I got why this is not working, because for example you can have ten radiuses of size 1000 and one of size 1, then I am wrong because I can just use ten big and get much bigger pieces than using all and max size of the min volume. And it passed :D. Anyway thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was setting minimal volume as high in the binary search, but I should use the maximal volume. The second problem was I was not passing maximal radius ^ 3 to the binary search function. Thanks for help